# Cakephp 3 Query contain join?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have 3 tables: `Users`, `Articles` and `Categories` and a join table `Articles_Categories`. Below are the associations I currently have. Are they correct?

CategoriesTable:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->table('categories');
    $this->belongsToMany('Articles', [
        'alias' => 'Articles',
        'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
        'joinTable' => 'articles_categories',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'article_id'
    ]);
}
```

ArticlesTable:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->hasOne('Users');
    $this->belongsTo('Users');
    $this->belongsToMany('Categories', [
        'alias' => 'Categories',
        'foreignKey' => 'article_id',
        'joinTable' => 'articles_categories',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'category_id'

    ]);
}
```

UsersTable:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
    $this->hasMany('Articles', [
        'dependent' => true,
        'cascadeCallbacks' => true,
    ]);
}
```

Now I have a view action inside ArticlesController that prints an article...

in the the View action I want get the username of the author and also the related categories using the article_id BUT my query returns all the articles

Here's my view action:

```
public function view($id = null)
{
      $query = $this->Articles->find()->contain([
          'Categories',
          'Users' => function ($q) {
              return $q
                  ->select(['username']);
          }
      ]);

    $this->set(compact('query'));
}
```

Comment: You are missing a ->where(['id' => $id])

Comment: Or rather you coud use `get` instead of `find`